# image infront of span

Tags: html, css

I have 3 labels (for a pricing table) and would like an image/icon in front of each text.
i'm thinking, to use :before pseudo element (or not) but the important thing is that the image **stays within the spans height, and keeps its proportions**. the height of the span is unknown, as it gets its value from parent element further up, which will be different depending on screen size.

there is 3 labels, i would like to replace the () with the image, on each label.
"basic" label with one image, "premium" with two images, and finally "ultimate" with 3 images.

```
<span class="label">
  () BASIC
</span>
<span class="label">
  ()()PREMIUM
</span>
<span class="label">
  ()()()ULTIMATE
</span>

<br/><Br/>
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/LS2fyR9.png"/>
```

```
.label{
  background-color:black;
  color:white;
  padding:10px;
  display:inline-block;
}
.label:before{
  content:""
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q3kngfs9/

any help with be much appreciated!

Comment: The `.label:before { content: ... }` can be an `url(..)` to an image, or some Unicode character, or a fontawsome icon. Like `content: '\xxxx'` where `xxxx` is a hex-code. You just have to design different `:before` classes. Or you can use those codes in the HTML like `&xxxx;`

Comment: Here's are some [Unicode Dingbats](https://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/2700-27BF) you can toy with, use `font-family: Arial, sans-serif` for the codes.

Comment: doesnt work if you put img inside the span and add height: min-content to .label and height: auto to img?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [existing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71955272/227299) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71955205/227299) assume the height of the text and set the image width to match that, meaning that the image would not stay the same relative size as the text when you increase or decrease size the font size.

If you use a [relative font size](https://dzone.com/articles/css-relative-font-size), such as `1em`, for the height of the image, and not set its width, you will have the image with the correct width/height proportions and that will adjust to the size of the text.

```css
#large {
  font-size: 36px
}

#medium {
  font-size: 24px
}

#small {
  font-size: 12px
}

.label {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: .8em;
  display: inline-block;
}

.label:before {
  content: ""
}

.label img {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: .3em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="large">
  <span class="label">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/LS2fyR9.png"/> BASIC
</span>
  <span class="label">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/LS2fyR9.png"/><img src="https://i.imgur.com/LS2fyR9.png"/>PREMIUM
</span>
  <span class="label">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/LS2fyR9.png"/><img src="https://i.imgur.com/LS2fyR9.png"/><img src="https://i.imgur.com/LS2fyR9.png"/>ULTIMATE
</span>
</div>

<div id="medium">
  <span class="label">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/LS2fyR9.png"/> BASIC
</span>
  <span class="label">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/LS2fyR9.png"/><img src="https://i.imgur.com/LS2fyR9.png"/>PREMIUM
</span>
  <span class="label">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/LS2fyR9.png"/><img src="https://i.imgur.com/LS2fyR9.png"/><img src="https://i.imgur.com/LS2fyR9.png"/>ULTIMATE
</span>
</div>

<div id="small">
  <span class="label">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/LS2fyR9.png"/> BASIC
</span>
  <span class="label">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/LS2fyR9.png"/><img src="https://i.imgur.com/LS2fyR9.png"/>PREMIUM
</span>
  <span class="label">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/LS2fyR9.png"/><img src="https://i.imgur.com/LS2fyR9.png"/><img src="https://i.imgur.com/LS2fyR9.png"/>ULTIMATE
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, thats what was needed, just some padding to line it up exactly.

Answer (score 3):

I think something like this. You can use pseudo-classes, which may be more semantically pleasing. But placing the img inline will do. Ideally, you give a width & height in the `img` tag

```html
<span class="label">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/LS2fyR9.png"/> BASIC
</span>
<span class="label">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/LS2fyR9.png"/>
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/LS2fyR9.png"/>PREMIUM
</span>
<span class="label">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/LS2fyR9.png"/>
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/LS2fyR9.png"/>
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/LS2fyR9.png"/>ULTIMATE
</span>
```

```
.label{
  background-color:black;
  color:white;
  padding:10px;
  display:inline-block;
}
.label:before{
  content:""
}

img {
  width: 2rem;
}
```

Comment: The only problem is that the OP said that height of the span is unknown, you are assuming the height of the text and setting the width of the image to match that height. That is, if you change your font size, the image will either be too big or too small.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean that?
I have put each image inside the span without height only max-width

HTML

```
 <span class="label">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/LS2fyR9.png"/> BASIC
</span>
<span class="label">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/LS2fyR9.png"/><img src="https://i.imgur.com/LS2fyR9.png"/>PREMIUM
</span>
<span class="label">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/LS2fyR9.png"/><img src="https://i.imgur.com/LS2fyR9.png"/><img src="https://i.imgur.com/LS2fyR9.png"/>ULTIMATE
</span>
```

CSS

```
.label{
  background-color:black;
  color:white;
  padding:10px;
  display:inline-block;
}
.label:before{
  content:""
}
.label img {
  display:inline-block;
  max-width:50px;
  margin-right:5px;
  vertical-align:middle;  
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/MAXXALANDER/geqn2vLc/3/

Comment: The only problem is that the OP said that height of the span is unknown, you are assuming the height of the text and setting the width of the image to match that height. That is, if you change your font size, the image will either be too big or too small.